# Locale keyword translation in English

Tags: symfony, locale

I read the tutorial and translation is working properly good. My problem is to handle keywords. Here you can see an example:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#creating-translations

I can run the keyword `symfony.is.great -> J'aime Symfony2`, when my language is French. But how can I translate `symfony.is.great -> Symfony2 is great`? Translate it to English. I miss that part in the docs or I don't really get it! My default language is Englisch!

I do have an messages.fr.xliff and messages.en.xliff.

Part of my messages.en.xliff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
        <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
            <trans-unit id="3">
                <source>symfony2.is.great</source>
                <target>Symfony is great</target>
            </trans-unit>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [section of the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#creating-translations) you shared just show you the different ways you can define your translation keys (real messages or keywords).

Take a look at [this part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#message-catalogues) of the doc. For the [translation process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#the-translation-process) to work fine you've to use the same key in your two message catalog files. The right translation is then loaded according to the `_locale` stored on the session.

Also, each time you create a new translation resource be sure to clear your cache so that the new file is taken into account.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this, but this is not the thing. How can I translate symfony.is.great -> Symfony2 is great. I do have a messages.en.xliff. Yes I cleard the cache.

Comment: When the _locale is set to "en_XX", Symfony will then load the translation messages from the right catalog "messages.en.xliff". Check your locale? You can also [force it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#forcing-the-translator-locale).

Comment: Okay, I tried it to force in French and Englisch. I guess symfony is not loading my messages.en.xliff file. But I cleared the cache by the command rm. I guess it is another problem. I get an error, when I do cache:clear...vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Lexer.php...llowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the translator service

```
$translator = $this->get('translator');
```

Then set the user locale ($language = 'en' or 'fr')

```
$translator->setLocale($language);
```

Or

```
$translator->setFallbackLocales(array($language));
```

After this, you can call translation function

```
$translator->trans('symfony.is.great');
```

Be sure that you are using the same keyword in both french and english catalog and try also to clear cache

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup
```